# TSQL - How to select some values from a table and some from SQL variables?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to return a table with columns names which are not defined somewhere else.
Under these columns names I want the records to contain data from different sources: a table, a previously declared variable and a const.

What is the right syntax to do so?

i.e.
columns names: "fromTable" (=select col1 from MyTable where id=1) , "fromVar" (=@MyVar), "fromConst"(=5).

thanks!

Comment: Elad, I don't understand ur question.  Can u elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

```
select <columns>,@myVar as FromVar, '5' as FromConst
from table
```